# Running .ksh Scripts from Solaris KornShell

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh

I have developed a few KornShell (ksh) scripts to run on Solaris. I run the scripts over Putty. On one server, I am able to run them as follows:

```
$ script.ksh
```

On the other, server, I need to run them as follows:

```
$ ./script.ksh
```

Otherwise I get a script.ksh not found error.  What would cause this difference?  I call scripts from within this script, and do not want to have to change all the scripts to append './' to each script invocation in order to get the scripts working.

Both servers uname -a reports following:

```
$ uname -a = SunOS servername 5.10 Generic_147440-10 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V245
$ echo $SHELL = /bin/ksh
```

Comment: check the difference in the $PATH variable on both machines and you'll figure it out.

Comment: After comparing both paths, it looks like the one that works has /opt/OV/bin in the path, and the other does not.  I believe that this is the HP Open View bin, so not sure if/why that would impact running a separate script.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear to.  But after looking at it again, there are two path values sperated by two colons, rather than 1. "/path1::/path2"  The $PATH that does not work does not contain one.  I see where you're going with putting "." in the path, so I'll try exporting that to the path.

Comment: In your controlling script, I'd add `PATH="$PATH:."` rather than relying on the user calling the script having "." in the PATH.

Comment: Good call, that seems to have worked well.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: An empty field in $PATH (i.e., Two adjacent `:`) refers to the current directory.  That would indeed explain the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `PATH="$PATH:."` to the main script.